# MSSQL in python 2.7

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008, python-2.7, pymssql

Is there a module available for connection of MSSQL and python 2.7?

I downloaded pymssql but it is for python 2.6. Is there any equivalent module for python 2.7?

I am not aware of it if anyone can provide links.

---

Important note: in the meantime there is a pymssql module available. Don't miss to read the answer at the end of this page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25749269/362951

Comment: Isn't 2.7 backwards compatible with 2.6? i.e. doesn't that module work in 2.6?

Comment: No while installing http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/downloads/detail?name=pymssql-1.9.908.win32-py2.6.exe&can=2&q= it check for python version and end the setup

Comment: There are snapshots for 2.7 http://build.damoxc.net/downloads/pymssql/snapshots/ ...if that helps.

Comment: I found one repository of python pakg hope it will usefull for all http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can also use [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki) to connect to MSSQL from Python.

An [example from the documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows):

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testdb;UID=me;PWD=pass')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select user_id, user_name from users")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row.user_id, row.user_name
```

The [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) library (mentioned in another answer), uses pyodbc to connect to MSSQL databases (it tries various libraries, but pyodbc is the preferred one). Example code using sqlalchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mssql://me:pass@localhost/testdb")
for row in engine.execute("select user_id, user_name from users"):
    print row.user_id, row.user_name
```

Answer (score 17):

If you're coming across this question through a web search, note that `pymssql` nowadays ***does*** support Python 2.7 (and 3.3) or newer. No need to use ODBC.

From the `pymssql` requirements:

> Python 2.x: 2.6 or newer. Python 3.x: 3.3 or newer.

See http://pymssql.org/.

Comment: From the MSFT python MSSQL driver page ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 ) 

"There are several python SQL drivers available. However, Microsoft places its testing efforts and its confidence in pyodbc driver. "

I doubt this was the case in 2014 though:)

Answer (score 5):

Install `pyodbc` using pip as follows: `pip install pyodbc`

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SOME-PC;DATABASE=my_db")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()


cursor.execute("insert into test_tb values(6, 'name')")

cursor.execute("select id, name from my_tb")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row.id, row.name
```

For details, see

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki

Comment: This pip install no longer seems to work (Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7.): `--compile failed with error code 1 in ...`

Comment: @MichaelMügge - `pip install pyodbc` works fine on Ubuntu 16.04 if you do `sudo apt install unixodbc-dev` first.

Comment: @GordThompson, Indeed. Important detail there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try out SQLAlchemy: 
The SQLAlchemy Object Relational Mapper presents a method of associating user-defined Python classes with database tables, and instances of those classes (objects) with rows in their corresponding tables.

You can refer following links:
1> http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/
2> http://www.rmunn.com/sqlalchemy-tutorial/tutorial.html